# Why am I allowed only 1 instance of a Tensorflow_IO AudioIOTensor at a time?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-io

I'm trying to learn how to handle audio data in Tensorflow and have downloaded the Kaggle Speech Accent Archive. I'm trying to compare two ways of doing this in Tensorflow. The first (I believe) reads the binary file, then in a separate step, decodes it with the knowledge the file is an mp3 file. The second method reads the file into an AudioIO tensor, which (I assume) figures out that the file is an mp3 file, stores some metadata, but then is "lazy", so it won't load all the data until specifically told to do so. the code I'm using to compare the two methods is as follows:

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
DATA_DIR = <Path to data>

data_path = pathlib.Path(DATA_DIR)
mp3Files = [x for x in data_path.iterdir() if '.mp3' in x.name]

def load_audios(file_list):
    dataset = []
    for curr_file in file_list:
        curr_file_path = curr_file.as_posix()
        audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(curr_file_path)
        audio1 = tfio.audio.decode_mp3(audio_binary)
        audio2 = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(curr_file_path)
        dataset.append([audio1,audio2, curr_file.name])
    return dataset

test = load_audios(mp3Files[0:3])
```

This results in the following 3 files being read:

```
>> test[0][-1], test[1][-1], test[2][-1]
('afrikaans1.mp3', 'afrikaans2.mp3', 'afrikaans3.mp3')
```

The AudioTensors - `test[0][1].to_tensor()`, `test[1][1].to_tensor()` and `test[2][1].to_tensor()` all give the same result:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1185408, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.00209848],
       [ 0.00333662],
       [ 0.00259154],
       ...,
       [-0.00472141],
       [-0.00558133],
       [-0.00375525]], dtype=float32)>
```

This matches the values for the EagerTensor given by `test[2][0]` (i.e. the last file in the list returned by load_audios), but `test[0][0]` and `test[1][0]` give the following two different results:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(916057, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.00905748],
       [ 0.01102116],
       [ 0.00883307],
       ...,
       [-0.00131128],
       [-0.00134344],
       [-0.00090137]], dtype=float32)>
```

and

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(968502, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-4.2711912e-05],
       [-3.0772724e-05],
       [-1.6126218e-06],
       ...,
       [ 2.9933560e-03],
       [ 4.1506598e-03],
       [ 2.9126832e-03]], dtype=float32)>
```

Why does this happen? How can I have multiple different AudioIOTensors at the same time?